# Salesforce AppCloud - Where is WAVE?

Tags: einstein-analytics, appcloud, thunder, lightning, heroku-enterprise

During dreamforce Salesforce has announced "app cloud". Part of app cloud are the following technologies:

- FORCE
- HEROKU ENTERPRISE
- LIGHTNING
- THUNDER

[image: App Cloud]

One technology plattform is missing: WAVE.

**Question:**

Is Wave part of AppCloud? (and why?)

Comment: Wave is limited to some customers/regions only. It can be a business decision to not project Wave now. It still requires lot of improvements to become a competitive analytics engine.

Answer (score 0):

Wave is a product , and heroky, force, lightning and thunder are technologies to develop your product

Comment: Thunder is a product: A complex event processing engine.

Answer (score 0):

App cloud includes following features:

- Force.com platfrom & Lightning
- Heroku Enterprise

It is introduced to customers for creating applications by point and click only. App cloud users can download applications from appexchange and use on their Salesforce instance.

Lightning Components are most useful for App cloud users, which can be downloaded from appexchange and create application using different type of components.

APIs access will also be provided so user can interact with the platform.

With more better App cloud license. Heroku Enterprise level access will be provided so a custom app (build on other technology but on heroku platfrom) can be used with Salesforce. It provides a database and processing unit on Heroku Environment.

**Wave** is a separate product. It is not a part of any other Salesforce product or technology. It is more about data processing, visualization and distributing apps built over it. It is itself divided in two parts, view and build. Appcloud doesn't come in this category.

Comment: and what about thunder?

Comment: Thunder is a also a separate platfrom, but it would be a part of Appcloud as add-on because Appcloud supports real-time API and Thunder needs it. @ChristianDeckert